# Dryer Fittings, Was NG, now LP, but Fitting on Back is Smaller than LP Flexpipe

Tags: dryer, natural-gas, propane

I'm trying to find the right conversion for this last part. I've already converted the dryer internally, but on the back on the dryer is a male threading that measures 1/2inch across [image: (PIC)]

And the flexpipe that I have says 3/8 nut [image: (PIC)] The nut is much bigger than the male part on the dryer. What part on Amazon or Home Depot would help me couple these? I'm not looking to buy a $30 new flexpipe if a coupler will suffice, unless you all think its unsafe. I have proper gas taping waiting for me.

So far my noob self is looking at this amazon part wondering if its what I need, but i clearly need some help as I do not know. [https://www.amazon.com/Industrial-Fitting-Reducer-Adapter-Female/dp/B07XDNK93G/ref=sr_1_10?dchild=1&keywords=3%2F8+male+to+1%2F4+female+adapter&qid=1606450984&sr=8-10](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07XDNK93G)

Answer (score 2):

The fitting your link leads to is likely NOT the fitting you need.

Your dryer has a male 3/8" NPT (commonly referred to as 3/8" pipe thread) inlet to which an adapter has been attached. The adapter changes the male 3/8" NPT to 3/8" male *flare* thread to fit a smaller flex supply tube than the one in your second picture. NOTE- NPT (pipe thread) and *flare thread* are distinctly and deliberately not compatible with each other, hence the use of an adapter.

To connect *your* flexible supply tube to the dryer you would need to remove the existing adapter from your dryer inlet and install a fitting that will fit your flex line. I *suspect* that the connection nuts on your flex line have 1/2" *flare* threads (I say "suspect" because your picture does not show the inside of the nut; disregard the size stamped on the nut because that is a reference to the nominal inside diameter of the flex tube itself, not the thread in the connector nut).

You will need this adapter: 3/8" FIP (female iron pipe; or "pipe thread") x 1/2" male *flare*. It will look like this:

[image]

NOTE- always ensure that your flex supply line is rated for use with the fuel supply (in your case propane/LPG). Also, the manufacturers of those flex supply lines generally consider them a "one time use" product and do not recommend re-using them.

Comment: Thank you I will try and take all this information in. I will try and remove the adapter you say is already on the dryer inlet. I tried to when I initially did the propane conversion and it would not move at all.

Comment: To further detail this for future people if any, this video helped me visualize what to do concerning the inlet for the gas. A Jimmy said the dryer inlet, someone already put some sort of adapted. I didnt know this and thought thats how it was standard. Si I will do my best to remove that as displayed in the video, and put on a proper fitting. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2ULPsmF3Ik